# How to draw a horizontal rule with a colour gradient?

Tags: gradient

[image]

Look at the two blue coloured rules with a colour gradient. This is what I'm looking for. Thank You.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can control the distance between the gradients and text changing the values `1em` for example. Also, the height for rectangle could be changed `1.5em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%dummy text only
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand{\gradient}[1]{\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[cyan,path fading=east] (0,1em) rectangle (\linewidth,1.5em);
    \node at (.5\linewidth,0) {\bfseries #1};
    \fill[cyan,path fading=west] (0,-1em) rectangle (\linewidth,-1.5em);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\gradient{Thermodynamics}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Adapting Sigur's answer to just give a command for the rule itself without the rest of the header, you might try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand{\tikzrule}[3][]{\tikz{\fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (#2,#3);}}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\tikzrule[cyan, path fading=east]{\textwidth}{1em}\\[.5em]
\textbf{Thermodynamics}\\[.5em]
\tikzrule[cyan, path fading=west]{\textwidth}{1em}
}

\noindent
\tikzrule{.9\textwidth}{3pt}\\
\rule{.9\textwidth}{3pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: colored horizontal rules]

The command `\tikzrule` behaves like the built in `\rule` except that it takes an optional argument which is passed as a tikz style. It is, however, a bit less robust than `\rule` in terms of what sorts of expressions can be used as its dimensions (e.g., `\dimexpr` doesn't work in `\tikzrule`).

Note that `\tikzrule` itself still works without the `fadings` tikzlibrary, although of course you need the library in order to produce the fading.