# How to make a horizontal line with varying opacity or gradient?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, rules, gradient

Can you please let me know how to draw a horizontal line with variable transparency similar to the figure attached below. Thank you!

[image]

There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334629/how-to-draw-a-horizontal-rule-with-a-colour-gradient) answered by @Emma and @Sigur, which addresses horizontal rule with a color gradient. But, I couldn't figure out how to make the horizontal rule fade at both ends.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

A quick adaption of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334631/103046) to the linked question yields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%dummy text only
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand{\gradient}{\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[black,path fading=west] (-0.5\linewidth,0) rectangle (0,1ex);
    \fill[black,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (0.5\linewidth,1ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\gradient{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version that controls the appearance of the rule with various pgf keys and draws the thing in one stretch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
left color=transparent!100,right color=transparent!100,
middle color=transparent!0]
\tikzset{faded rule style/.style={},faded rule/.cd,color/.initial=black,width/.initial=\textwidth,
height/.initial=1ex,style/.code=\tikzset{faded rule style/.style={#1}}}

\newcommand{\FadeRule}[1][]{\noindent\tikz{\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/faded rule/##1}}
\tikzset{faded rule/.cd,#1}
\path(-\textwidth/2,0) -- (\textwidth/2,0);
\fill[faded rule style,color=\pv{color},path fading=fade out] (-\pv{width}/2,-\pv{height}/2)
rectangle (\pv{width}/2,\pv{height}/2);}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\FadeRule

\lipsum[2]

\FadeRule[color=blue,height=1em]

\lipsum[3]

\FadeRule[color=red,width=0.7\textwidth]

\lipsum[3]

\FadeRule[style={opacity=0.5}]
\end{document}
```

[image]